# How do I pull the current user onto the page for this practice project? I am struggling with the backend Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, next.js, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I cant seem to pull any data whatsoever onto my page from the backend. Any guidance or resources would be helpful. Right now, im just trying to display whoever is logged in. I can add users to the backend through  a table called customuser, but I dont know how to retrieve any data such as the current logged in user

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
import requests
import json

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True
    )
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username')   
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useGlobalState } from '../context/GlobalState';
import authService from '../services/auth.service';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import Link from 'next/link';
import axios from 'axios'; 
import Layout from './layout';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const ProfilePage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [postData, setPostData] = useState({ title: '', content: '' });
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([]);
  const [userLogs, setUserLogs] = useState([]);
  const {state, dispatch} = useGlobalState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);


  const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior
      const { title, content } = postData;
  
    try {
      if (!title || !content) {
        alert('Please fill in all fields.');
        return;
      }
  
      const response = await axios.post('https://8000-ryanhowardh-howticultur-x28i0huza91.ws-us104.gitpod.io/api/users/', {
        title,
        content,
      });
      
        console.log('Post created:', response.data);
        setPostData({ title: '', content: '' });
        
      } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
      console.error('Error creating post:', error);
      alert('An error occurred while creating the post. Please try again later.');
    }
  };


  // useEffect(() => {
  //   fetchPosts();
  // }, []);
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to fetch current user information
    const fetchCurrentUser = async () => {
      try {
        const token = state.user.token; // Get the JWT token from your global state
        const response = await axios.get('http://example.com/api/current-user/', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        });

        setCurrentUser(response.data); // Set the current user state
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching current user:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchCurrentUser();
  }, [state.user]);




  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setPostData({
      ...postData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
  



  const { favorites } = router.query;

  const favoritePlants = JSON.parse(favorites || '[]');

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2>User Profile</h2>
          {currentUser ? (
            <div>
              <p>Name: {currentUser.first_name} {currentUser.last_name}</p>
              <p>Email: {currentUser.email}</p>
              {/* Display additional user information as needed */}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          )}
        </div>
        
        <h2>Favorite Plants</h2>
        <ul>
          {favoritePlants.map((plant, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{plant.common_name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;
```

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_simplejwt import views as jwt_views
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import *
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UsersViewSet)
router.register(r'plants', PlantListViewSet)
router.register(r'user-favorite-plants', UserFavoritePlantsListViewSet)
router.register(r'user-notifications', UserNotificationListViewSet)
# router.register(r'community-posts', CommunityPostListViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('user/signup/', UserCreateViewSet.as_view(), name="create_user"),
    path('user/login/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_create'),
    path('token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('user/<int:pk>/', UserDetailViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name="user_detail"),  # Example: /user/1/
    path('plant/<int:pk>/', PlantDetail.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name="plant_detail"),  # Example: /plant/1/
    path('user-favorite-plants/<int:pk>/', UserFavoritePlantsListViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name="user_favorite_plants_detail"),  # Example: /user-favorite-plants/1/
    path('user-notifications/<int:pk>/', UserNotificationListViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name="user_notification_detail"),  # Example: /user-notifications/1/
    # path('community-posts/<int:pk>/', CommunityPostListViewSet.create), 
    path('community-posts/',views.createPost), 

]
```

```
class UserCreateViewSet(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    # authentication_classes = ()
    
    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                json = serializer.data 
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view([ 'POST'])
def createPost(request):
    print(request)
    serializer = CommunityPostSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data) 

@require_POST
def upload_file(request):
    # Get the file from the request
    file = request.FILES['file']
    # Save the file to a location
    with open('path/to/file', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(file.read())
    # Return a success response
    return HttpResponse('File uploaded successfully.')
```

Can anyone give me guidance or a push in the right direction?

All i want right now is to be able to display who the current user that is logged in